# What is this function called when I run this C++ program?

Tags: c++, static

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;


class foo
{
private:
    static int cnt; // number in memory 
    static int nextid;  // the next id number 

public:
    int id;     // not shared - each object has it's own

    foo()
    {
        cnt++;      // update the counter of alive foos
        id = nextid++;  // assign an id
        cout << "foo # " << id << " is alive " << endl;
    }

    ~foo()
    {
        cnt--;
        cout << "foo # " << id << " is dead " << endl;
    }

    void stats()
    {
        cout << "I am foo number " << id << endl;
        gstats();
    }

    static void gstats()
    {
        cout << "Objects currently alive: " << cnt << endl;
        cout << "Total number ever created: " << nextid << endl;
    }

    foo( foo &f)
    {
        cnt++;      // update the counter of alive foos
        id = nextid++;  // assign an id
        cout << "foo # " << id << " is alive and copied from " << f.id << endl;
    }    
};

int foo::cnt = 0;
int foo::nextid = 0;

void dmy1( foo a )
{
    cout << "called dmy1 ( by value) id is " << a.id <<  endl;
}


void dmy2( foo &a)
{
    cout << "called dmy2 (by reference) id is " << a.id << endl;
}

int main(void)
{
    foo::gstats();

    foo f1, f2;
    f1.stats();

    dmy1(f2);

    foo::gstats();
}
```

This is the code my professor gave me to practice C++ static code.

But when I run this program, I have a question.

Objects currently alive: 0

```
Total number ever created: 0
foo # 0 is alive 
foo # 1 is alive 
I am foo number 0
Objects currently alive: 2
Total number ever created: 2
foo # 2 is alive and copied from 1
called dmy1 ( by value) id is 2
foo # 2 is dead 
Objects currently alive: 2
Total number ever created: 3
foo # 1 is dead 
foo # 0 is dead
```

This is the output.
But I don't know the reason why this function is called 
Could you explain?

```
foo( foo &f)
{
    cnt++;      // update the counter of alive foos
    id = nextid++;  // assign an id
    cout << "foo # " << id << " is alive and copied from " << f.id << endl;
}
```

And, also,  Why static void gstats(){ ~ } is called after destructing foo #2 ?

Comment: It's called a copy constructor. Your prof should probably have spent more time on the basics before dropping such messy code on you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, i try to explain what happens

First it is showed no objects exist at this point

```
foo::gstats();
```

Now f1 and f2 are declared and created on stack (2 objects alive)

```
foo f1, f2;
```

f1.stats is called and shows the current state

```
f1.stats();
```

f2 is passed by value (**copyed on stack with copy constructor call `foo( foo &f)`**) to dmy1 (3 objects alive)

```
dmy1(f2);
```

after leaving dmy1 it's scope (stack variables used by it) is destroyed and f2's copy gets it's destructor called (2 objects alive) and this status is displayed

```
foo::gstats();
```

Then `main()` is left and it's scope is destroyed as well and f1 and f2's destructors are called (0 objects alive)

Answer (score 1):

The function is called [copy constructor](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_constructor). It's called because you pass the object `f2` to `dmy1` by value and a copy of the object is constructed. If you would change the object `a` inside `dmy1`, `f2` would stay the same - because you implicitly constructed a copy when you passed the parameter in by value.

`foo#2` is destructed when you exit the function `dmy1,` because it's only alive inside that function. So it's destructed before calling `gstats.`

Answer (score -1):

It is copy constructor, as it was said. But copy constructor should have been declared like this:

foo(**const** foo &f)
{
...
}

Comment: It is common practice that a copy constructor accept a `const` reference.   But there are cases where it is appropriate that the reference not be `const`.

Comment: Could you tell where it is appropriate to declare without const? 
I thought constructor should always initialize new object without changing others.

Comment: Before C++11, it was a main means of implementing transfer semantics - for example, the (now removed) `std::auto_ptr` did exactly that.   Move semantics (introduced in C++11) provides an alternative, but there are projects where moving to C++11 isn't permitted (yes, they exist, albeit the constraints are often non-technical) a non-`const` copy constructor is the practical alternative.